# Difference Ways to Read Channels

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I am curious of why different ways of reading values from a channel result in different behaviors. Provided the code:

```
mychan := make(chan int)

go func() {
    i := 0
    for {
        mychan <- i
        <-time.After(time.Second * 1)
        i++
    }
}()
```

The goroutine "streams" a sequence of integer infinitely to a `mychan` channel. After this code, if you read directly with `<-mychan` like so:

```
fmt.Println(<-mychan)
```

This prints "0" as expected. If you keep repeating, it keeps reading:

```
fmt.Println(<-mychan)    // 1
fmt.Println(<-mychan)    // 2
//...
```

However, using the looping mechanism, it blocks infinitely.

```
for i := range mychan {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

That means that this mechanism can only reads from a closed channel, right?
However, with `select` method, thing gets wierder:

```
for i:=0; i<=10;i++ {
    select {
    case <-mychan:
        fmt.Println(<-mychan)
    }
}
```

Now it prints alternately, like 1, 3, 5, 9, ... every 2s as if `select` was switching between `mychan` and some other invisible channel. Adding another `case` makes the case (no pun intended):

```
for i:=0; i<=10;i++ {
    select {
    case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("foo")
    case <-mychan:
        fmt.Println(<-mychan)
    }
}

// now prints 1, foo, 3, foo, 5, foo, ... every 1s
```

As trivial the question as it may seems to some of you, I'd appreciate if anyone can explain and enlighten me.

Comment: Note that your second code `case <-mychan: fmt.Println(<-mychan)` reads from mychan **twice** and discards the first result. That's my you see 1, 3, 5, .... You might want `case i <- myhcan: fmt.Println(i)`

Comment: All channel receive operations are the same (expect of course the 2 value assignment, which can show the status of a closed channel). The only difference in behavior you have is discarding every other received value in the select statement.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/CEMKqJF3ya <- This code snippet "proves" that the range keyword will work with open channels. I am pretty curious why the program hangs. Does it know it won't be closed somehow?

Comment: @BenjaminKadish: it doesn't hang, it reports a deadlock because no goroutines can proceed. This doesn't happen If there is another goroutine doing _something_ https://play.golang.org/p/8CwgCaw4Qq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior from

```
for i := range mychan {
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Appears to result from running examples on [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bMvtp4UVZX) When I ran the code locally the program prints out one value every second indefinitely. It would be cool if there is some code analysis tool they are using on the server to figure out if the code will run forever.

As Volker points out your second example is reading the channel twice per print statement. You can fix this with

```
for i:=0; i<=10;i++ {
    select {
    case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
        fmt.Println("foo")
    case x, open := <-mychan:
        if !open { return }
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good. However, the first case should be omitted or it will only print "foo" after an initial print. Also, the second case is missing `:=`

Comment: Foo appears to print out for me? I'm not sure I understand (thanks for the assignment fix)